# Streamlit extras dataframe explorer Filtered Results- How to export to an Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I imported the streamlit extras package and used the dataframe explorer by passing my dataframe.

Now my question is , how to export the results to Excel that were produced by dataframe explorer filters and selection.

I am aware how to download a csv/excel in streamlit in general, but here the case, i need to export that were filtered by selections from dataframe explorer on UI

Any help will be highly appreciated, here is the code i am using for displaying the dataframe explorer

```
df = dataframe_explorer(df)

st.dataframe(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save dataframes to `.csv` files using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

EDIT:
I do not see a way to export a filtered dataframe from Streamlit to `.csv` directly. Their docs show how to export a dataframe to `.csv` using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/how-download-pandas-dataframe-csv) and the `st.dataframe` function [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.dataframe) does not give any information about returned objects with their own methods.

It looks like you will need to apply your filters on the `pandas.DataFrame` with methods like [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Comment: how to capture the filtered data frame options is my question

Comment: updated with references to Streamlit docs